# Magento2 : how to change admin startup page programmatically

Tags: magento2, login, backend, admin-login

I want to change landing page of admin based on some condition how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The startup page is determined by the method `Magento\Backend\App\BackendApp::getStartupPage()`.
You can write an `around` or `after` plugin for that method and return your desired value.

Comment: actually i want to pass one parameter with this redirect url